# GoLang - encoding/json.Marshal or fmt.sprintf?

Tags: json, go

Which would be faster?

```
data := fmt.Sprintf("{\"TEST\":3, \"ID\":\"%s\"}", Id)
```

OR json marshalling a struct like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly depends on what you're trying to do, you should benchmark it and see.

However for your very specific example, the fastest way is just use basic string concat like :

```
data := `{"TEST":3, "ID":"` + Id + `"}`
```

Answer (score 6):

In the case of JSON with basic data types (string, bool, int) `fmt.Sprintf` is faster. Benchmarking shows that it is on the order of twice as fast as `json.Marshal` for rendering a very small JSON object, with the spread in performance increasing as more data is added.

The benchmark results for rendering a JSON object using both methods (10,000,000 times each for clarity) are as follows:

```
Benchmarks for rendering a small JSON object
Time taken to render JSON object using json.Marshal:     8.747821898s
Time taken to render JSON object using fmt.Sprintf:      4.452937712s

Benchmarks for rendering a larger JSON object
Time taken to render JSON object using json.Marshal:     32.100388801s
Time taken to render JSON object using fmt.Sprintf:      10.392861696s
```

Note that these results do not hold if your JSON object contains more complex data types like lists and nested objects.